# Probability that a bivariate normal random variable is at least $c$ from the origin

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d normal random variables with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $(X_1, X_2)$ determine the coordinates of a point moving randomly in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What is the probability that the point is at least $c$ from the origin?

This is the same as $[1 -\mathbb{P}\left(||(X_1, X_2)||_2 < c\right)]$.

This can be determined by integrating as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(||(X_1, X_2)||_2 < c\right) = \int_{-c}^{c}\int_{-\sqrt{c^2 - x_2^2}}^{\sqrt{c^2 - x_2^2}}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\text{Exp}\left(-\frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\:\:dx_1dx_2$$

(here $||(\cdot, \cdot)||_2$ is the standard Euclidean norm) then subtracting this from 1.

Is there an easier way to go about this? I have not put a humongous amount of time into trying to solve the above integral, but...it does not look directly promising.

Comment: Change to polar coordinates

Comment: If you really want to solve the integral you should follow the "polar coordinates" suggestion, but if you simply want to compute the probability, use the fact that the sum of $n$ independent squared standard normals is chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom (i.e. the probability you want is $1 - \chi^2(2;c^2/\sigma^2)$).

Comment: Note that the question is a little simpler if you recast it as standard normal variates with $c$ replaced by $c/\sigma$. i.e. Let $Z_i=X_i/\sigma$ and ask the corresponding question of $Z$; it's then simple enough to do in the head. (edit... Yep, I checked just now by actually doing it in my head.)